# What is the correct mapping for php in subfolders in nginx? (picocms, including mod-rewrite)

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm trying to create a server mapping in nginx so that I can reach `http://example.com/blog`. I am using the following configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /home/www/blog;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;

    location /blog/ {
         location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

If I go to `http://example.com/blog` it does not work, but `http://example.com/blog/index.php` does at least for the welcome page. Unfortunately, browsing to another sub-category doesn't work. This will lead to a URL like `http://example.com/blog/food/`. Weird thing is: if I remove the location /blog/ everything works fine. With it, it keeps downloading (Chrome) the index.php file.

I think the URL rewriting makes it not work (although the URL in the browser looks correct).

Can you suggest me ways to debug nginx behaviour like this? What am I missing that it works for `http://example.com/food`, but not for the subfolder one?

Btw: I modified pico's base_url property in the config.php to match either `http://example.com` or `http://example.com/blog` (depending on the scenarios I tried).

Comment: Tried the same, works on index, but any sub-directories doesn't (gives nginx welcome page) `location /wiki { root /home/u/projects/; index index.php index.html index.htm; try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
 location ~ \.php$ {
                        try_files $uri =404;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                }
        }`